# Excel: How to automatically store data gathered from a website scrape?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have set my workbook to retrieve data from a website which gives prices of stocks.

It refreshes hourly. I then have some cells that make calculations based on the stock prices using a simple formula. I am trying to make it so that every time the data refreshes, it recalculates based on the updated data, and that gets put into a new row.
Here is a picture showing what I need. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb7JO.jpg (the first hour has been done, but my question is how to automate the rest).

***https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3fHS.jpg***: shows both the data and calculations.

So for example, after running it for 12 hours, I want it to have 12 rows showing the results of the calculations. (1 row per hour).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the data structure of your external data source, but see the attached image. It's a Web Query scrape with auto-updates where I add a column with a formula pre-filled to every row of the spreadsheet.  This satisfies your auto-fill need, but also, because the formula column you create is not part of the Named Range array of your external data source, that column, and any similar formula columns you add, are not limited by what you *can't* do inside the named range area of the web query...

[image: Adding Calculations to Excel WebQuery]

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I need. 
My data set is just a table of 100 cryptocurrencies and their prices, and from that I am calculating min, max prices. Every hour, the data updates/refreshes. This image describes what i need:
https://imgur.com/a/NRD2pA4

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Your excel data is functioning as a timestamp log. For it to create the records (new excel calc row), in my experience, you would either need a macro to trigger after the refresh to create the new row, *or* you would need a separate data source table for each hour then set each data source table to refreah only once per day at preset times.